# Новое окно из инпута javascript

Tags: javascript, input

здравствуйте дорогие мои друзья. Очередной вопрос из серии "брутальное извращение". Сразу скажу  javascript у меня == ноль. По этому нужна Ваша помощь.
есть инпуты допустим

```
<input type="text" name="incoming_number" id="incoming_number" class="form-control"> 
<input type="text" name="sender" id="sender" class="form-control">
```

как сделать так чтоб при двойном клике внутри инпута открылось новое окно. Например для инпута с `id="incoming_number"` открылось incoming.php а для инпута с `id="sender"`открылась sender.php. Новое окно необязательно можно и сделать переход по ссылке...

Comment: Под новым окном вы хотите сказать новая вкладка?

Comment: нет именно новое окно )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//запускается анонимная функция по двойному щелчку. В тело функции можете вставлять всё, что угодно. Здесь обыкновенный переход на другие страницы innum.html, и  sender.html. Вы можете сделать свои функции, в этом случае посмотрите как взаимодействовать с объектом XMLHttpRequest
 var inNum = document.getElementById('incoming_number'); //получаем элемент 'incoming_number'
 var sender = document.getElementById('sender'); //получаем элемент 'sender'
 inNum.ondblclick = function() {
     alert("Go to incoming_number page");
     window.location = "innum.html";
 }; //запускается анонимная функция по двойному щелчку. 
 sender.ondblclick = function() {
     alert("go to sender page");
     window.location = "sender.html";
 }; //запускается анонимная функция по двойному щелчку.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>
                Document
            </title>
        </meta>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input class="form-control" id="incoming_number" name="incoming_number" type="text"/>
        <input class="form-control" id="sender" name="sender" type="text"/>
        <script src="regular.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Доброе утро.
Можно начать со следующего:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test(){
    location="http://localhost/test.php"
  }
</script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="incoming_number" onclick="test()" id="incoming_number" class="form-control"> 
 <input type="text" name="sender" id="sender" class="form-control">
</form>
```

p.s. только зачем так делать - непонятно. и по поводу нового окна до конца непонятно. это должно быть всплывающее окно или что?

Comment: Весьма благодарен Вам. Новое окно обычный window.open )

Comment: тогда просто измените функцию, напишите там создание окна, а не перевод на другую страницу.

Comment: да есть такая уже функция просто не знал как в инпут ставить )